# Secure way to have one view from database on remote gate controller

Tags: networking, mysql

I am working on a project regarding reservations. 
We have programmed an online web application using django and mysql that is hosted on a server. We are now implementing a gate controller (opens the gate for authorized people) on a remote area using raspberry pi.

What would be a good way to keep the database in raspberry pi updated ?

Our solution right now:

1. Server periodically (10 minute intervals) dumps one view of mysql data (reservation start, pin, user ID).
2. Raspberry Pi uses sftp to transfer that dump.
3. Raspberry Pi drops last database and makes a new database.

The view is quite small since there probably will never be more than 1000 people using it (over 2 years around 50 people). The dump file is quite small. Also there might not be connection to raspberry pi at some times and then it operates over latest database provided. Also ssh-keys have been swapped between server and raspberry pi.

Is there any other ways that we are not thinking of or is this the best way? Maybe there are some mysql builtin functionalities that we don't know of ?

Comment: Why dump the data at all? You obviously have a connection, so you could just run replication slaves.

Comment: I have not heard of this replication, is it secure and fast?

Comment: WIthin a second or two, generally, not ten minutes. Go check the MySQL documentation to set it up.